# Sliding retrieval

Tags: code-golf, sliding-puzzle

## Thanks, Uncle (the story)

My slightly mad uncle recently left for the space colonies, and passed his pallet goods business to me. The rectangular warehouse is full of pallets of goods except for the one square by the door, and I've just received the first list of pallets ordered by customers to be sent out today.

Fortunately I have a carefully written map of where each pallet is, and my mad uncle engineered several mini robots which can move a pallet into an adjacent space, much like a sliding 15-puzzle. I don't care where the pallets end up, though, I just want the pallets on the list to arrive in order by the door.

The question is, what series of commands must I give the robots in order to retrieve the required pallets?

## The challenge

Given

- the size of the grid (rows, cols)
- a list of pallets (by their current location) to retrieve in order

You must output a list of grid positions corresponding to which position is to be moved, and which direction. If there is only 1 direction available you may optionally omit that. The pallets will be removed immediately upon arrival by the door (at one corner, index N in the examples).

## Worked example

```
01 02   label the contents  A B
03 04                       C D
05[  ]                      E _

Request: 03 (contents is C)

Command 0: 04
D moves into the (only) adjacent space at index 06
Result: A B
        C _
        E D

Command 1: 03
C moves into the (only) adjacent space at index 04
Result: A B
        _ C
        E D

Command 2: 05
        A B
        E C
        _ D
Command 3: 06  
        A B
        E C
        D _
Command 4: 04
        A B
        E _
        D[C]
(C removed having arrived by the door)
```

## Limits and freedoms

- Maximum grid size is 100x100
- Challenge is code-golf
- Solution must execute within 2 minutes on some real-world machine
- You can choose your indexing, command syntax, input structures and so on, as long as it's consistent.
- I've chosen to use the grid locations for the commands, but conceivably you could emit the value in the element instead (plus a direction) as they are unique.
- If you wanted to make an animation of the state (especially for a large grid), I'm sure that would be entertaining!

## Examples

### A: 3x2, 1 pallet

```
01  02
03  04
05 [__]

Request: pallet at 03

Valid solution: 05,03,04,06,05

This leaves the following state:

01  02
04  05
__ [03]
```

### B: 15-puzzle, 1 box

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14[  ]

Request: box 01

Valid solution: 14,13,12,11,06,01,02,07,12,11,06,07,12,11,06,07,08,13,12,11,06,07,08,09,14,13,08,09,10,15,14

02 07 03 04 05
08 12 13 10 14
06 11 09 __[01]
```

### C: 3x2, 4 boxes

```
01 02
03 04
05[  ]

Request: 02,04,01,05

Valid solution: 04,02,01,03,05,06,04,05,02,06,03S,05E
Pallet taken at:                    ^  ^     ^       ^

Indicating directions with NSEW

Final state:

03 __
__ __
__ __
```

### D: 10x10, 2 boxes

```
10x10, request boxes at 13,12 (row 1, cols 2 & 1 with 0-index)

Valid solution: (90,80..20, 19,18..12, 22,32..92, 93,94..100) x 15, 90.
```

### E: 4x1, all

```
4x1: 01 02 03 [ ]
Req: 03,02,01 (only valid order)
Optimal solution: 03,02,03E,01,02E,03E
```

### F: 100x100, 3 near the door

```
100x100
Req: 9900,9899,9898
Result: 9000,9989,9000S,9898,9898E,9000S
```

[Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17688)

Comment: if boxes 2 and 3 are requested, is it illegal for 3 to pass by the door while you are moving 2 toward the door?

Comment: @Jonah: No, or none of the scenarios would be solvable unless the first box was n-1 or n-c. The only thing special about the space by the door is that when the next pallet on the list arrives there, it is immediately removed by my eccentric forklift operator.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (Node.js) - <s>425</s> <s>424</s> <s>420</s> 395

```
(n,m,L)=>(s=Math.sign,G=[...Array(n*m).keys()],i=k=n*m-1,G[k]=-1,R=[],M=j=>{-G[j]-1&&R.push([j,i]);[G[i],G[j]]=[G[j],G[i]];i=j},X=j=>{while(i%n-j%n)M(i+s(j%n-i%n))},Y=j=>{while(y(i)-y(j))M(i+n*s(y(j)-y(i)))},y=i=>(i-i%n)/n,L.map(e=>{J=()=>j=G.indexOf(e);while(J()%n-n+1){m>1&&y(j)-y(i)||M(y(i)?i-n:i+n);X(j+1);Y(j);M(j);m<2?i=k:0}while(J()+1-n*m){X(n-2);Y(j+n);X(n-1);M(j);n<2?i=k:0}G[k]=-1}),R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVbb9s2FH62f8XZQxOypjQru9oKXRRDYTSwWyAdhhSCHjSJtslIlCfRSQTHvz07pGTH9dKtA2xR/Pid@@GRSu6SOq3k2ni6zMRTLgxU4q@NqA1/IpoVbEb5hNR8npiVX8ulZlMe@b7/tqqShujXBfVvRVMTGjPJbzkCXsCm0W3Mcb3mUczmXPHJ1ptGKvaCs7Nrf72pVyRSTMY0jKaRjJk9i3lkF2aBOJRc7diNk7xfyVwQ@Up76pWmcyIHNcE3DxFKd@zzEakhknoNUdTR9Oua2I1nYUttuMRYpJP8XrOZXyRrIlD6ihOMUvGpL3UmHj4uiKBhq/KKULSlBwHdFhN0/6Dw8XHu7L2Rnh6jMRreEIW08DMywrl9FJcXbzAp4@HuoGsQeDZn2xuivQvHbSW1F3RC@iDUZXFH2TV9Cvv9xUanRpYa7pJcZokRbX1YWhZForOawrbfswVcVjIDDi@XKez37HlkH34u9NKsvCBGut7kOR62KmbvbSIQHSK0N@Avyupdkq5IBwCfWJNOQCK3g6OhNeJQdYQGDsWfXACRcAlDeHxEuQmHI18spvaH6uTQRdjrmVVV3oMW9/CuqsqKnL/XLiWA1ZOpqMdwDgPUPMDVm7gNJhYld60Dzl8bHDbC3lPZ4N72xgO2RvjMU5annnnK8ZSnTniZ4z2g/J6ZWaZqPNkcxe2uUfJnTbIHChMIbJTPWHPA8BzOzlAH/XrMLlbQpYEkU0kqtPmvwK0HrvgSC87bkn9N/1tjRLE2YEooyjsBdtNAvUZD32xGxfDd/zQjNb6VabpZS5F9m7moC4l1Nm0zR907686Oe6/r7UuY7XsOM/3inUDfZ1FLj7sA/vXu9HoteTDo3NtRd6OOrNp8zA7t/I90fLDVzHNY40OYGu5FJXAgm0qKO5H556hv1@/b9jI4on9LauwAjLbf24IeQzAcMii6dTaGaMgCdsF@iGHHTiktYfQrG/3CRj@z0U9s9OMx70tFL/Awpf2DE4fRYLqhkJa6LnPh5@WSnP@ONKmXrnRXnz5@8GsMSC/loiGGtin6gj8VWlSJE0FwY4cezjIbvLtZ@3mEkXffKmJ8zYxf4H9GwxNtf7Tj8iVth0l6JP88T08VfeqkQdbtDG7rQcOnvwE)

Takes n,m and an array of pallets, returns a list of commands where each command is a 2-element array of the location of the pallet to move and the location of the space to move it to.

There's probably a better strategy than what I used, but posting as is for now.